# WPF Background Two Tone

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to do something so simple but cannot get anywhere with it. I've been trawling the net trying to find a clear example or tit bit of information but every article I find is showing the exact same simple example.

All I want to do is have a background to a list box item that is two tone but without a gradial blend between them. So far I have:

```
<Setter Property="Background" >
    <Setter.Value>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Color="#ACC6E0" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#DCE7F5" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I've tried plenty of different things but all I end up with is a variant of a gradual gradient not a two tone equal split.

Many Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add two stops at the same offset:

```
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#ACC6E0" Offset="0"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#ACC6E0" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DCE7F5" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DCE7F5" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

In fact you can drop the end points:

```
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
        <GradientStop Color="#ACC6E0" Offset="0.5"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#DCE7F5" Offset="0.5"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

Comment: Works like a charm thank you, was rather obvious in the end ;)

Comment: @Paulie Waulie: Glad that helped :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add extra GradientStops:

```
<LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
  <GradientStop Color="#ACC6E0" Offset="0"/>
  <GradientStop Color="#ACC6E0" Offset="0.5"/>
  <GradientStop Color="#DCE7F5" Offset="0.5"/>
  <GradientStop Color="#DCE7F5" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Comment: This works thank, up voted both answers but voted for H.B purely because it was possible with two lines.  Thanks a lot.