# Is it possible to stop the vertical scrollbar from pushing the DataGrid columns/header to the left?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, scrollbar

Is it possible to stop the vertical scrollbar from pushing the DataGrid columns/header to the left? (See picture)

Alternatively, is it possible to style the small circled area so it doesn't just show up as a white square?

[image: GridView]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colour of that rectangle above the scrollbar is the Background property of the DataGrid. So, for example, if you wanted to make it yellow you can set

```
<DataGrid Background="Yellow" ...
```

The downside of this (potentially) is that the background then affects your whole DataGrid, including any space not taken up by data rows:

[image]

One solution, if you wanted the rectangle in question to be yellow but not the space below the data rows, might be to design a custom brush that rendered yellow for a strip the same width as the column headers, and white for the remainder.

Comment: This was the better option of the two, and I could put a gradient background in there to make it look like I wanted it to.

I thought I'd tried this, changing background on the DataGrid that is, but discovered that I'd an override at last minute preventing my changes to take effect. :)

Comment: Great. Just in case you're wondering, you can make a brush with two brushes and no gradient between the two by putting two stops in the same place. As described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546837/wpf-background-two-tone

Answer (score 6):

Please use the following template (the ColumnSpan does the trick):

```
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
            <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
                        <Grid>
                            <DataGridColumnHeader IsHitTestVisible="False" Name="PART_FillerColumnHeader"/>
                            <ItemsPresenter/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Interesting option, it works but  you can still see a separator and a resizecolumn mouse pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this helps, but one approach I have used in the past to separate columns from their headers and present them separately.

The column definitions are defined in resources:

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <GridViewColumnCollection x:Key="siColumnCollection">
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        ...
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Fish"/>
            </GridViewColumn>
    ...
```

Then the headers and the listview are presented separately, both referencing the same resource:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Columns="{StaticResource siColumnCollection}"/>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelList}">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="siNormalRowTemplate">
                <GridViewRowPresenter Columns="{StaticResource siColumnCollection}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

(I can't promise this XAML works exactly as written, but it gives you the idea).

The advantage of this arrangement is that you are free to treat the headers and the main body of the list separately. So if you want to put in some filler immediately after the GridViewHeaderRowPresenter, you are free to do so.

**Edit**: This solution works if you have a GridView, but unfortunately does not work for DataGrid. I can't see an equivalent way to split the header and rows in DataGrid so this answer will only work if you're prepared to swap the DataGrid for a GridView. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question was done several years ago, but I would like to post my solution in order to help others facing the same issue.

Based on imil4eg's solution in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64356870/13802688) I also created a border control to fill the Column=2, Row=0 empty space of the ScrollViewer's ControlTemplate. But, I added also a margin="-1,0,0,0" to prevent a little gap between the header and the border I created.

So, his solution is adding the line bellow as can be observed in his answer:

`<Border Background="White" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="2"/>`

Mine is the same, but with the described margin:

`<Border Background="White" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="-1,0,0,0"/>`

Hope this can be helpfull to someone!